# The title of a Mars-based movie

Tags: story-identification, aliens, mars

Can anyone could help me remember the name of a "journey to mars"-type movie. All I remember is that you see the groups of guys (about 3) chill behind some rocks and they see a group of these short green alien humanoid-shaped beings. There's a trough of water and the aliens are drinking from it. But the one at the end is slightly weak-looking, so then the group attacks it and feasts. Then either this pile of rocks starts to build itself into a organism thing and attacks them, or it attacks the human guys. But it was at least 3 times taller than them and made out of rocks.

I know these if very vague but I've tried and can not find what this is, so if any of you have a clue THANK YOU.

Answer (score 35):

You are talking about [Galaxy Quest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0177789/), it's not about Mars but the scene does take place on what looks like a Martian landscape. The pertinent scene is on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1kYFNGuJAo) if you want to watch it to make sure. Here is also a picture of the rock monster:

[image: The rock alien from Galaxy Quest]

Comment: @mason not a problem at all, glad I could help

Comment: (There is a [deleted comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40898622#40898622) from the OP confirming that this is indeed the answer, so this can stay closed as a dupe.)